# Symfony2 Many fields to the same property with many-to-many relationship

Tags: symfony

I'm creating a form from an entity that I have some properties and one of them has a many-to-many relationship, which I need to create more than one field to work with.

**Products Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="StructureItems", inversedBy="product")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_structure_items",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="structure_item_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $structureItems;
```

**StructureItems Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Products", mappedBy="structureItems")
 */
protected $product;
```

So in my form type what I'm doing is something like below.

**Form Type**

```
->add('field1','entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'WidetiHarmoniaBundle:StructureItems',
                'label' => 'Tecido da Fronha',
                'empty_value' => 'Selecione o tipo de fronha',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('psi')
                            ->where('psi.itemType = :itemType')
                            ->setParameter('itemType', Enumeration::FIELD_1)
                            ->orderBy('psi.itemName', 'ASC');
                    },
                'mapped' => false,
            )
        )

        ->add('field2','entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'WidetiHarmoniaBundle:StructureItems',
                'label' => 'Tecido da Fronha',
                'empty_value' => 'Selecione o tipo de fronha',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('psi')
                            ->where('psi.itemType = :itemType')
                            ->setParameter('itemType', Enumeration::FIELD_2)
                            ->orderBy('psi.itemName', 'ASC');
                    },
                'mapped' => false,
            )
        )
```

In this case I'm getting the value of the unmapped form fields in my controller and adding into the structureItems property manually. Something like...

```
$entity->addStructureItem($form["field1"]->getData());
$entity->addStructureItem($form["field2"]->getData());
```

The problem is that I don't know if this is the correct way to do it, or if there's a better solution for it. Maybe its not a good deal to spend more time in it if is not the best solution.

I hope that there is a way to map this fields to the same property, that could me help to avoid a lot of manual coding work.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You certainly want to embed a collection :

```
$builder->add('structureItems', 'collection', array(
    'type'         => new StructureItems(),
    'allow_add'    => true,
));
```

More info in the [Symfony cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)